# FCM API: not receiving any notification from PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a notification message from my `localhost` server like this:

***Javascript:***

```
function send_notification(empno,charge,op){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/notification_server/firebase_server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
              "employee": empno,
              "body":op
        },
        cache: false
    })
}

(async() => {
    await send_notification("Hi Leo","This is a test notification");
})();
```

***PHP:***

```
<?php

    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
    use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

    $factory = (new Factory)
               ->withServiceAccount('admin.json')
               ->withDatabaseUri("https://nfr-qtr-electric-billing-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com");
    $deviceToken = '.....'; //I have my actual device token here
    $messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
    $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken)
               ->withNotification(['title' => $_POST["employee"], 'body' => $_POST["body"]]);

    $messaging->send($message);

?>
```

---

I am reading the notification like this in my `android`:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            sendLocalNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody);
        }
    }

    private void sendLocalNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, record_viewer.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //Notification icon
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1234, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

---

Upon executing the code, I don't receive any notifications. In the network console, it shows that the `AJAX` request has been sent and there are no errors in my `php` server code. I tried logging the `notificationTitle` and the `notificationBody` in my `FirebaseMessagingService`, but it too doesn't show anything. Am I doing anything wrong? Why am I not receiving notification? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your payload, you're sending [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) with `employee` and `body` fields.

However, your message handling implementation uses [getNotification()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage#getNotification()) which is for notification messages. It won't return any value for `notificationTitle` and `notificationBody` since there's no `title` and `body` fields set in the payload.

You should use [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage#getData()) instead. It should look something like [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#:%7E:text=a%20data%20payload.-,if%20(remoteMessage.getData().size()%20%3E%200)%20%7B,%7D,-//%20Check%20if%20message):

```java
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    if (true) {
        scheduleJob();
    } else {
        handleNow();
    }
}
```